# How to send Facebook Page Like request to friends using Facebook graph API in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api

i am building a new application using asp.net(c#) such that user can send a page request directly to their friends.Is there any possible solution through facebook graph api?? I already did that for event invitation but need some codes/hint/links for page invitation.

Comment: did you get some info about this?